# python 3 - limiting invalid inputs

Tags: python, loops, syntax, python-3.3

I am trying to limit the number of invalid inputs before the program closes. So I need the program to loop back to the original input question if the input is invalid. My limit of attempts will be 3.

I am not sure what syntax to use or how I should structure it.

heres an example of my code:

```
min_mile = 0

def main():

    print('hello',name,', today we will be doing some standard to metric conversions.')
    print('The first conversion will be to convert miles to kilometers.')
    MileToKm()


def MileToKm():
    mile = float(input('What is the number of miles that you would like to convert? ')
    mile_conv = mile * 1.6

    if mile_conv > min_mile :
        print ('The result would be', format(mile_conv,'.2f'),'kilometers.')
    else:
        exit(print('invalid input'))

main()
```

So right now if the input after the conversion comes out as negative its considered invalid. I need to modify it so the user has three attempts to input a valid number before the program closes.

How would I go about this?

I am in python 3.3.3

Comment: remove `print` inside `exit()` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the exit paths of `MileToKm` to look like this:

```
if mile_conv > min_mile :
    print ('The result would be', format(mile_conv,'.2f'),'kilometers.')
    return True

else:
    return False
```

Then wrap your function to handle retries:

```
def TryMileToKm():
    attempts = 0

    while attempts < 3:
        attempts += 1
        if MileToKm(): break

    if attempts >= 3:
        print 'Invalid input'
        exit(1)
```

This is not the most idiomatic way of doing this, but I tried to keep the intent obvious.

EDIT very well, here it is:

```
def miles_to_km(miles):
    return miles * 1.6

def read_miles(prompt):
    miles = float(input(prompt))
    if miles < 0: raise ValueError()
    return miles

def read_miles_retry(prompt, retries = 3):
    while retries > 0:
        try:
            return read_miles(prompt)
        except:
            retries -= 1
            print('Invalid input')

    raise ValueError()

def main():
    try:
        kms = miles_to_km(read_miles_retry('Miles? '))
        print(kms)
    except:
        exit(1)

main()
```

Comment: Fair enough. There you go. Note that in this version, each function has a single responsibility, and takes exactly 1 role. This is the main improvement

Comment: ok, I understand some of this code, could you explain a few things to me? when you def read_miles for example you put (prompt) in the parenthesis. what is the purpose of this?                                      also when you def main(): you put try then kms = miles_to_km(read_miles_retry(miles?). I dont understand how that works. your setting the variable "kms" to all that but is the purpose to call the functions?   sorry alot of this syntax we havent discussed in my class, while i can derive what the meaning and purpose of most of it is. this is way beyond anything we have learned so far.

Comment: functions take arguments. The syntax for defining a function with arguments is `def name(arg1, arg2,... argn)`. Inside the body of the function, arguments are available for use. When calling a function by name from outside, you can pass in the arguments that will reach the body, in order between the parenthesis. You should try a python tutorial :)

Comment: well I am in a basic python class and I have been using a few methods of learning but mostly reading from a required text book. My professor is no help and will explain nothing, so im basically teaching myself. which while I have understood a majority of the things we have covered there is plenty which i don't fully understand.